# Files get bloated during Upload

Tags: php, fine-uploader

I'm trying to upload a video file and everything works fine except the fact, that the file gets bloated by ~3300% during the upload process. A video with 1.4 MB has the size of ~46 MB after the upload.

During the upload the total size of the file differs on each progress-callback by several bytes (logging the passed `total`-argument).

The HTML looks like this:

```js
<div id="media-upload"
    data-accept="video"
    data-endpoint="/path/to/endpoint"
    data-chunk-size="20000"></div>
```

The JS looks like this:

```js
$upload = $('#media-upload')

$upload.fineUploader({
    autoUpload: true,
    debug: false,
    maxConnections: 1,
    request: {
        endpoint: $upload.attr('data-endpoint'),
        forceMultipart: true
    },
    multiple: false,
    chunking: {
        enabled: true,
        partSize: $upload.attr('data-chunk-size')
    },
    cors: {
        expected: true
    },
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'ogv'],
        acceptFiles: $upload.attr('data-accept') + '/*',
        itemLimit: 1
    },
    callbacks: {
        onComplete: onComplete,
        onProgress: onProgress
    }
});

function onComplete() { /* fancy DOM-Manip */}

function onProgress() {
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

The `qq-template` is the same as in the jQuery-Basic-Setup-Demo.

Has anybody experienced the same phenomenon or does have a solution for this? I'm using the traditional upload with a PHP-powered endpoint.

Best regards
Emanuel

Comment: The issue of bloated files is in your server code for sure.  As far as the total changing a bit in the progress callback, this happens when the files are chunked and are sent as multipart encoded POST requests.    There is no easy/reliable way to determine the exact size of a multipart encoded request sent by the browser client-side, so we do a bit of estimating and adjust this estimate with each chunk.  This is done to ensure the total value sent to your progress callback is as close to the total number of bytes the browser will send as possible.

Comment: This might come in handy: `$file_size = number_format($_FILES['file']["size"]);`

Comment: The issue is server side, so you'll need to show your server code.

Comment: I'm using the PHP-code from the "fine-upoloader-server"-repo (https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/php/traditional).

Comment: Okay, one should pass the chunkSize as integer. Sorry for wasting your time ...